# 'Cancel' will not cancel OK Google

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ok-google

This is a minor niggle, but I am sure that OK Google used to let me say 'cancel' to cancel it; now, it's doing a Google search for 'cancel'!  Is there a way I can get it to actually cancel instead?

Answer (score 1):

"Thank You." Seems to work. It will stop listening, but also will pop up a list of Ok Google commands. Which is annoying and unneeded. Personally I just say"open (last app)" and resume my life.

Comment: Reference: ["Saying 'Thank you'", on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2pwsew/if_you_accidentally_say_ok_google_say_thank_you/)